# Group data, preferably with the same number of elements in each group

Tags: excel, excel-2010, grouping, pivot-table

Suppose I have this set of data:

```
1
1
5
6
6
10
11
```

Is there a way to get this?

```
Value:Repeated
1    : 2
5    : 1
6    : 2
10   : 1
11   : 1
```

I've got 2550 rows so doing it manually is not an option.

Also, is there a way to group the above table in a way such that each group has approximately the same number of elements (with the exception of the last group)?

```
Range : Elements
1-5   : 3
6-10  : 3
11    : 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a PivotTable. So add a label (say `Digits`) at the top of your column first and have `Digits` in Row Labels and `Count of Digits` in Sigma Values. Grouping depends somewhat on which version of Excel.

[image: SO16590644 example]

Comment: How do I put `count of digits` in sigma values?